# Vtiger Customer Portal login with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, authentication, portal, vtiger

I am beginning as a web developer (and a new vtiger user) working on a phonegap app with several features, like that the customer can login through the customer portal, so they can access their trouble tickets. My problem is that I have no idea how to do this without using PHP, and I cannot use PHP because Phonegap doesn't support it.

I know how to make a simple login form with phonegap like [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap). But I have no idea how I could do something similair with the vtiger customer portal.

My question is: Is it possible to log in to the customer portal with a phonegap app, and how?

Thanks in advance!

(PS. Sorry for my bad english.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap apps can provide a login functionality to another web application by calling making an HTTP request to some URL that authenticate the passed user credentials. The main difference is that in PhoneGap this request typically done in an AJAX style rather than a full page submission like is common for a web browser.

In both cases though the goal is to establish a session with your application server so that subsequent requests to the app server can determine who is making the request and if that user has permission to do what the request is asking for.